# What does this 我却为你万千感慨 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I do know the meaning of each word in the following sentence.

```
我却为你万千感慨
```

But I still cannot understand the meaning of the whole sentence. Google translates it as.

```
I feel so emotional for you
```

I doubt about it. The hard part for me to understand this sentence is because of the present of `却`.

So what does the above sentence mean?

Comment: Consider “却” as “但”, like "但我为你万千感慨 ". Meanwhile, grammatically, “但” is a conjunction word and “却” is an adverb, so they will appear in different places in the sentence

Comment: Just add a "but" before your translation.

Answer (score 4):

Google's translation isn't off too much.

却 is an adverb which is used more or less like "yet", "however" or "and yet" in English. I say "and yet" because I often see it used as a conjunction, in place of 反而.

For example:

> 这句话那么简单，**却**点燃了我 (= this sentence is so simple, and yet it set me on fire)

万千 means "a myriad", also in English used figuratively to elegantly express a large quantity.

感慨 means something like "full of sorrow". [Mdgb says](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%84%9F%E6%85%A8) "rueful". [Zdic defines](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%84%9F%E6%85%A8) it as 心生感触而发出慨叹. Which essentially is a feeling of such sorrow that you can't withhold sighs and moans. Also, given the proposed synonyms (感叹, 慨叹) it seems it's used in a verbal position. It's seems used like a stative verb.

So if you put it all together:

> 我 (I) 却 (however, yet) 为你 (for you) 万千 (myriad) 感慨 (rueful, feeling sorrowful)

It roughly means the subject's feelings are many and nuanced, but all of them related to sorrow and sadness.

A fluent translation (somewhat poetical) might be something like:

> And yet for you I let out a multitude of sighs

or, taking 万千 less literarily, so many feelings that the subject is overwhelmed.

> And yet for you I'm overwhelmed by sorrow

Comment: There is no verb in the sentence, isn't there? Is it also correct for oral and written to use sentence without verb in Mandarin?

Comment: @OConnor I think 感慨 is the verb, but it's one of those with shifting lexical role. So there's maybe two interpretations. 1. 感慨 is a stative verb (adjective) and 万千 is the intensity adverb, so 万千感慨 is the same construction as 很高。2. 感慨 is a normal intransitive verb.

Answer (score 3):

It is from a lyrics of 《相思的债》

The complete sentence is

```
你闯进了我的心里 真情灌溉
我却为你万千感慨 默默等待
```

Girl: You rushed into my heart, filled it with water of love. In the meantime, I am emotional a lot for you, waiting quietly.

The 却 shows the comparison that the boy is active while the girl keeps waiting, even though she is emotional.

Lyrics are written in a rather twisted order to make the sound beautiful, but that also make it hard to understand.

Comment: Yes, one of my favorite karaoke songs. Here's the link to hear how those words are pronounced --- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aH68xMSTX74

Comment: So `却` in this context means: In the meantime?

Comment: @OConnor It basically means "but". However, the contrast is not 180 degrees. It looks like a comparison between counterparts. So I think, "In the meantime" can be a better translation than "but".